# How to make my web server wait?

Tags: java, sockets, webserver

I'm coding a little web server, which is returning `Hello` using `3000` port:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class HttpServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        //http://localhost:3000
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3000);

        while (true) {
            //Waiting for socket
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            //The main process
            new SocketProcessor(s,ss).start();
        }
    }

    private static class SocketProcessor implements Runnable {
        private Thread t;
        private Socket s;
        private ServerSocket ss;
        private InputStream is;
        private OutputStream os;

        private SocketProcessor(Socket s,ServerSocket ss) throws Throwable {
            t = new Thread(this, "Server Thread");
            this.ss=ss;
            this.s = s;
            this.is = s.getInputStream();
            this.os = s.getOutputStream();
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                readInputHeaders();               
                writeResponse("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>");


            } catch (Throwable t) {
                /*do nothing*/
            } finally {
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }
            }
            System.out.println("Client processing finished");
        }


        public void start()
        {
            t.start();
        }

        private void writeResponse(String s) throws Throwable {
            String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                    "Server: Server\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                    "Content-Length: " + s.length() + "\r\n" +
                    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
            String result = response + s;
            os.write(result.getBytes());
            os.flush();
        }

        private void readInputHeaders() throws Throwable {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while(true) {
                String s = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(s);
                if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make my server wait for second before response. I was trying to use something like this:

```
readInputHeaders();
t.wait(1000);
writeResponse("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>");
```

But my browser says `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the run method of the `SocketProcessor`.

The method `wait` is not the right one to call for your purpose.

See also:

[Thread.sleep JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

The methods `wait`, `notify`, `notifyAll` are defined on `java.lang.Object`
and are used for synchronization between threads. They are not generally
for the purpose of making a thread sleep for a certain amount of time.

Comment: While I basically agree that sleep is preferred, do you have an explanation as to why wait would not perform the expected task?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, of course, but it's kind of long. I would need to write about object monitors, wait, notify, notifyAll and all that. OK, I added one sentence anyway.

Comment: but `wait` has a timeout after which it is automatically released, doesn't it?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, but do you know what `wait` is about? Check this old article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071214/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-3--thread-scheduling-and-wait-notify.html

Comment: I know a bit about wait, I have used it to synchronize threaded operations and all, what I don't get here is that `wait` should pause the thread until the timeout is reached or notify is called on the waited object. It wouldn't occur to use `wait` where `sleep` would be appropriate. But I wonder why the timeout mechanism of wait does not work in this case. Does it get interrupted or something?

Comment: @njzk2 Because wait can only be called from within a synchronized block (synchronized on the object on which it's called). The OP didn't do that, so an `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown. And then the control flow goes to the OP's empty catch block, while the browser gets no response.